# How can I pass value from Flutter App to PHP mysql query then return data from it?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I already tried this:
[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371762/post-value-to-a-php-file-to-execute-sql-query-and-get-back-data-in-json-format)

But it wont work! Nothing appears in the App!
This is my flutter code to set Data .. num is equal to 1 so I can get the first user:

```
  Future setData() async {
      final response = await http.post(theUrl, body: {"id": num});
setResponse = json.decode(response.body);
return setResponse;
 }
```

and this is for getting theData Flutter Code:

```
    Future getMethod() async {
String theUrl = "http://192.168.8.53/flutter_test/phpConnect.php";
var res = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
responseBody = json.decode(res.body);
return responseBody;
 }
```

this is my php getData.php code:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$userId = $_POST['id'];

$makeQuery = "Select * From tableName Where id=" .$userId;
$statement = $connection->prepare($makeQuery);
$statement->execute();
$myarray = array();

while ($resulteFrom = $statement ->fetch()){

array_push(
$myarray,array(
"id"=>$resultFrom['id'],
"header"=>$resultFrom['header'],
"body"=>$resultFrom['body']
   )
  );
 }
echo json_encode($myarray);

?>
```

Thanx in Advance <3

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with **placeholders**. Currently, you're using `prepare()` wrong. You're still injecting completely unescaped user data into the query directly instead of using placeholders, which makes the `prepare()` pointless and your query unsafe..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you help me with that issue?

Comment: You need to expand on "wont work". What actually happens? What debugging have you done? Have you checked the browsers console for errors? Have you  checked the network tab in the browser while making the request to see what data is sends and what the response is?